# C# code to UML Diagram

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, uml

I have Visual Studio 2010 ultimate edition. I have the following code in a file named test.cs:

```
 public interface IXClass
{
    void Test();
}

public class ConcreteXClass1 : IXClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ConcreteXClass2 : IXClass
{
    public void Test()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

How do I create a UML diagram for the above code?  Where can I get the option in VS to generate the UML diagram for the above code?

Comment: You ask for "class diagram" - "UML diagram" is more general term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select "Architecture" -> "New Diagram...".
2. Select "UML Class Diagram" and create a new modelling project.
3. Select "Architecture" -> "Windows" -> "Architecture Explorer".
4. Select "Solution View" -> "Solution where Test.cs is located" -> "Test.cs" -> "Select classes/interfaces" and drag these to diagram surface.

Comment: can it automatically generate the dependent class diagrams and show the relationship? i can only add the class one by one, which is not very convenient.

Answer (score 3):

In to Solution Explorer (top-right) right-click the project (or just one source file) you are working on and click "View Class Diagram".

Comment: That doesn't generate the UML diagram.

Comment: Yes it does but maybe not on the Express Edition (I am not sure). Be sure to save your .cs first.

Comment: @Rocky Singh: It does for me.

Comment: I am seeing no arrow linked between interfaces and concrete classes.

Comment: @Rocky Singh: Yes, that's weird, but if you hover over the circle above the concrete class it displays the interface name. It does generate arrows for a class extending another class though.

Comment: Interfaces are not represented by arrows in an UML diagram with VS, only circles.

Answer (score 1):

Add >> New File >> Class Diagram, then drag drop the all the CS files that you want to generate the UML for. also you can generate classes from the Class Diagram.